# How to pass values in front end react js to backend springboot

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot

In the front end, I have created a login module that has a user name and password, and login button it on clicking login button it should pass the values to spring boot

```
export default function Login() {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");

  function validateForm() {
    return username.length > 0 && password.length > 0;
  }

  function handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  function LoginUser(){
    console.log(username, password);
  }

  return (
    <div className="Login">
      <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <Form.Group size="lg" controlId="username">
          <Form.Label>Username</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control
            type="username"
            value={username}
            onChange={(e) => setUsername(e.target.value)}
          />
        </Form.Group>
        <Form.Group size="lg" controlId="password">
          <Form.Label>Password</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control
            type="password"
            value={password}
            onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
          />
        </Form.Group>
        <Button block size="lg" type="submit" onClick={LoginUser} disabled={!validateForm()} >
          Login
        </Button>
      </Form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Let me know how to add the values to the backend

Comment: Spring Boot + React does not works like Spring MVC. You send/receive data via RESTful web API.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to send the request with the username and password either to a server or some third party API to authenticate.

There are plenty of tutorials online, though their relevance will depend on your backed framework. Here is an example: https://www.cluemediator.com/login-app-create-login-form-in-reactjs-using-secure-rest-api.

Answer (score 0):

You're nearly there. You just need to add an actual RESTful API call (`POST`, most likely) using React's built-in `fetch` API to the `LoginUser()` function, which is already being called upon a user clicking the `Button` component (and should have access to `username` and `password` variables via `useState`). So it might look something like:

```js
function LoginUser() {
  console.log(username, password);
  (async () => {
    await fetch('http://path-to-spring-boot-api/', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ 'username': username, 'password': password })
    });
  })();
}
```

#### Edit based on OP's comment

```js
function LoginUser() {
  const body = { 'password': password, 'username': username };
  console.log(`body json object that will be POSTed is :${body}`)
  (async () => {
    await fetch('http://path-to-spring-boot-api/', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },

      body: JSON.stringify(body)
    });
  })();
}
```

Also, be careful with logging passwords in production front-end applications (or anywhere else!).

Comment: okay, but in the request body the format is { 'username': username, 'password': password } but in console , response json format is  {  'password': password ,'username': username}  ,why and how it can be done in request body format in console.

Comment: The order of keys shouldn't be important to any back end that is going to handle the request, but it is possible to order them however you want (e.g., alphabetically)—please see my update.

Comment: Hi! I have a problem while I sending an object to my spring boot application, the problem is that react put the name of a costant in the object and spring doesn't like it, do you know anything to help me to solve it, I added the question in my profile, thanks